# Magento2 How To Update Cart Subtotal After Checkout cart page is load

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart

[image]

Does anyone know how to update cart subtotal after checkout cart page is loaded?

Comment: What issue are you face in mini cart?

Comment: hey @mitesh i have got my problem's solution, i have just done using checkout pre index observer and update cart totals using quote object